# How to override svn repository?

Tags: svn

How to override svn repository using subclipse?
Or, in last case, by command line?

Comment: What do you mean by "override" exactly?

Comment: @Pekka I mean delete all content on the repositore and put my local content there. By the way, I'm the only one using this repository, so it will not cause problem to anyone.

Comment: obs. its occuring a lot of inconsistence errors and I'm not having success to just commit. And its so much errors to correct, I prefer override the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by just commiting from the command line.
Subclipse its really being a nightmare here... I don't know if its becouse of Ubuntu. I had used it beautifully in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

svn switch --relocate svn://repos/

Comment: in this <http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html> page the example is "svn switch --relocate file:///tmp/repos file:///tmp/newlocation". Nothing equals to yours. I wonder, by "svn://repos/" you mean the full svn url?

Comment: I'm, trying to understand what exactly this command do. It don't seen to be made to override the repository..